# Invoking g++ via `subprocess.run` in Python causes "exec format error" in executable

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

Using Python 3.7, I am trying to invoke g++ to compile and build a C++ file via

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subprocess.run(
        executable="/usr/bin/g++",
        args=["/some/path/source.cpp", "-std=c++17"],
        shell=True
    )
```

When I run the script, the executable builds. I then `chmod u+x` it. However, when I try to execute the executable, it fails and says:

```
-bash: ./a.out: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I've read some other posts regarding this error however none are applicable. For some reason, this method fails, however when I run `g++` natively in my terminal, it works as expected.

**Edit**: When I invoke `file a.out`, the output is

```
a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Does this output for `file a.out` match what you get when invoking `g++` in terminal and testing *that* executable?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No; when I use native g++ in the shell, I get 'a.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=2f95aee23ec12609bd3d110ae2793b63e3705f12, not stripped'

Comment: You shouldn't need to `chmod +x a.out`. It should already be executable, so that is suspicious already. Can you check?

Comment: Please check that the `g++` you run in Terminal is the same as the one you run in the Python subprocess, using `type g++`

Comment: Please try removing `a.out` before you run the Python in order to be certain you are looking at the file it generated and not something else.

Comment: Finally, there may be some differences in your environment variables between your Terminal and what the Python subprocess gets. So run `env > term.txt` in the Terminal and `env > subp.txt` in the subprocess then `diff term.txt subp.txt` to see if anything differences exist which might affect compilation.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It seems very likely to be one of the three issues you raise, but for the last one he might need to sort the `env` outputs before comparison: `diff <(sort term.txt) <(sort subp.txt)`.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt also just to do `ls -l a.out` and check that its modification time is recent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `executable` parameter to `subprocess` is only rarely needed.  With `shell=False`, it overrides `args[0]` as the program to run (allowing `argv[0]` to be customized, as for a login shel).  With `shell=True` (which should be avoided when possible, partly because it doesn’t do what you think with your carefully separated `args` list), it replaces the implicit **`/bin/sh`** invoked to run the command.  The standard option to run one command is `-c`, so you ran

```
/usr/bin/g++ -c /some/path/source.cpp -std=c++17
```

which indeed produces a relocatable (*i.e.*, a `.o` file).  `a.out` is not the normal name for such, but perhaps it’s a fallback when the directory containing the source is not writable.

Comment: So, to clarify, I should move the executable parameter to the first element of the args array, and use shell=False?

Comment: @RichardRobinson: Yes: that’s the normal, good way to use it.